# Using excludes with rsync

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I am trying to use rsync to automatically backup my personal files in /home/usr to an external drive.

Of course, my /home/usr directory contains a number of hidden files (for config, etc.), such as .adobe/, .cache/, etc. I would like to exclude these from my rsync backup, as well as temporary files.

However, I also have some .files and .directories I would like to keep, like .htaccess for some websites and app config files.

I am using this rsync command:

```
rsync -acuvz --delete --progress --exclude-from '/home/chase/rsync/Files-excludes.txt' /home/chase/ /media/chase/Files
```

And the contents of `Files-excludes.txt` is:

```
/Dropbox
/Ubuntu\ One
/.*
*~
```

However, I'm afraid that this is going to exclude the mentioned .files and .directories, especially because the -a option recurses through subdirectories. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
--exclude-from file
```

and make an exclusion file to then describle the files and folders you want to exclude

Something like

```
/home/usr/.*
```

in the file should just exclude the . directories in /home/usr/

See more here
http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/10/10/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Steve. Aren't exclusions relative to the source directory? I feel like the exclude above would only exclude files in /home/usr/home/usr/.*

I'll give it a try with `--dry-run` and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, I did this with a dry run, and none of the . directories were excluded.

I also edited my question to reflect the actual command I'm using.